# What value should be used for an LED with current rating of 350mA ~ 1000mA

Tags: led, current, resistors

I looking to make a basic LED circuit using a CREE LED from eBay. My only problem is calculating what value resistor that I need. If it is really neccesary, I could purchase an LED driver, but before doing so I would just like to know what value resistor I need to operate the LED.

I know how to work out the value for the resistor, my problem is that I do not know what the current I should use to calculate it is. The current of the LED is stated as 350mA ~ 1000mA, so what value do I use, is any value between these okay?

Just incase, here's the specs of the LED:
**Colour:** Red
**Wavelength:** 620-625nm
**Luminous Intensity:** 62
**DC Forward Voltage:** 2-2.4V
**DC Forward Current:** 350mA-1000mA
**PCB Size:** 20mm
**View Angle:** 130 Degree

I know this is probably a really stupid question with a really simple answer, but my 2 functioning brain cells don't know what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated, have a nice day!

Comment: Also: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/348675/led-resistor-calculation-and-resistor-wattage

Comment: 1000 mA will need a big heatsink. 350 mA can use a smaller heatsink. How much light do you want? How much power have you got? How much heat can do dissipate? Do you feel lucky punk?

Comment: You or nobody else can calculate the resistance unless you know what supply voltage you will be using.

Comment: @Neil_UK Luck? What is that mystical thing you speak of?? I'll probably only be putting in around 3V, it's only the one LED. I don't want to break it, cause when I order it, it'll take a few weeks to arrive, so ordering another one would be somewhat irritating and time consuming, I'm trying to save on space anyways. I'll try the 350mA then, thanks!

Comment: If the supply is only 3 V, then a resistor will give very poor current control, with so little voltage across it. Consider a constant current source, or more volts across the resistor, or you may have to depend on ... luck.

Comment: @Neil_UK What is a constant current source? Would a battery count? as the forward voltage of the LED says 2-2.4V, my plan was to simply use 2 AAA batteries in series to power the circuit and use a resistor so that I wouldn't break the LED. How would I go about making the circuit in a better way, not so dependent on luck? would it be as simple as putting more volts in??

Comment: The Q is a different scenario than an LED string: it’s a single, high-current LED that OP wishes to drive on a low voltage (not 24V). Different system, different parameters, *different solution*. So, *not* duplicate, at least as far as the referred Q goes.

Comment: I disagree. The second answer to the duplicated question is generic and seems to apply in this case. I don't think it is reasonable to provide a different answer for every combination of LED and source.

Comment: @hacktastical So do I need to run it at a high voltage?

Comment: @Elliot Anderson, If that were the criteria, *every single LED current limiter question* - a new-to-electronics chestnut if there ever was one - would be ‘duplicate’. Why stop there? Any Vf question? Dupe! Ohm’s law question? Dupe!

Comment: @MagSkull85, you can increase the voltage to reduce the influence of Vf, but at the expense of power shed in the resistor, which will be a lot (see below). Try the calculations and decide from there.

Comment: buy one of those cheap adjustable current DC-DC converters and turn the current screw until you get the right amount of glow. (search `"DC-DC" "CV-CC"`)

Answer (score 0):

It isn’t possible to know the dropping resistor value without knowing also your supply. Know also that depending on your setup, the variation in Vf will result in large variations in current if you have both a low supply *and* low value for the dropping resistor.

Nevertheless, you can calculate the dropping resistor, same as for any other LED, using the following equation:

- R(drop) = (Vcc - Vf) / I(led)

Power shed in the resistor is of course:

- P(drop) = (Vcc - Vf) * I(led)

---

If you want to protect the LED, a way to do that is configure an adjustable LDO to sense the current.

But if you’re going to that much trouble... might as well use a DC-DC buck LED driver, like this one: https://www.diodes.com/part/view/PAM2804

Here it is on a board that can go in a flashlight: https://www.mouser.com/new/diodes-inc/diodes-inc-pam2804ev1-evaluation-board/